# How to find shared entries between two pandas data frames and use them to create an identical column in both data frames?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Using pandas, I have created two data frames similar to the below.

```
input_df1 = pd.DataFrame({'names':['phone,mobile,cell','boat,ship','car'], 'values':[1,3,3]})
input_df2 = pd.DataFrame({'names':['cell,phone','car,automobile', 'boat'], 'values':[3,7,1]})
```

[image]

I would like to change the 'names' column to contain only names that are found in both data frame. The goal is have the values for these names automatically group together in comparison plots. The final data frames should look something like what is shown below.

[image]

It is important that the names are not reduced to only one name if there are more than one name available in both data frames, as in row zero above. Rows that do not have common names between them should preferably be removed (but I can do this manually beforehand also). Preferably this should also be done without a for loop since the actual data frame is over 50k rows.

I have tried playing around with `input_df.names.str.contains()` and `input_df.names.isin()`, but I can't figure out how to find a name in `input_df1` that matches a name in `input_df2`, compare them for the shortest name, and then replace the longer one with the shorter (which is what my mind thinks should be done).

Comment: How do you want to handle the case if one line would say `"boat, car"`?

Comment: Luckily, in the data frames I encounter that is never the case, the names only appear once in the same frame.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one strategy to do it.

```
# your data
# =======================================
input_df1 = pd.DataFrame({'names':['phone,mobile,cell','boat,ship','car'], 'values':[1,3,3]})
input_df1

               names  values
0  phone,mobile,cell       1
1          boat,ship       3
2                car       3

input_df2 = pd.DataFrame({'names':['cell,phone','car,automobile', 'boat'], 'values':[3,7,1]})
input_df2

            names  values
0      cell,phone       3
1  car,automobile       7
2            boat       1
```

We first convert **flat** name records to a **stacked** name records.

```
# groupby-tostack function
# ===============================
def func(group):
     return pd.Series(group['names'].values[0].split(','))

stacked_names1 = input_df1.groupby(level=0).apply(func)
stacked_names1

0  0     phone
   1    mobile
   2      cell
1  0      boat
   1      ship
2  0       car
dtype: object

stacked_names2 = input_df2.groupby(level=0).apply(func)
stacked_names2

0  0          cell
   1         phone
1  0           car
   1    automobile
2  0          boat
dtype: object
```

Next, get the common names by using `np.intersec1d`.

```
common_names = np.intersect1d(stacked_names1, stacked_names2)
common_names

array(['boat', 'car', 'cell', 'phone'], dtype=object)
```

Use `.isin` to keep the valid names.

```
stacked_names1.isin(common_names)

0  0     True
   1    False
   2     True
1  0     True
   1    False
2  0     True
dtype: bool
```

Finally, convert stacked records back to flat records, again by a groupby on outer level index.

```
def func2(group):
    return pd.Series(','.join(group.values.tolist()))

input_df1['names'] = stacked_names1[stacked_names1.isin(common_names)].groupby(level=0).apply(func2).values
input_df1

        names  values
0  phone,cell       1
1        boat       3
2         car       3

input_df2['names'] = stacked_names2[stacked_names2.isin(common_names)].groupby(level=0).apply(func2).values
input_df2

        names  values
0  cell,phone       3
1         car       7
2        boat       1
```